# Block some sources from Google Now?

Tags: google-now

I'm seeing some cards from the Daily Mail when I look at Google Now. How can I prevent Google Now surfacing cards from sources that I dislike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap the menu button at the top right of the offending card, there should be an option for "Never show stories from the Daily Mail".